# How instantiate classes dynamically based on configuration in Java

Tags: java, spring

Is there any way to change which class is going to be instantiate in Java (in Spring If it is possible). 
For example, using Refection and reading configuration from a database it could be possible but Reflection is heavy technique because the number of created object is going to be very high.
So that, what I need is create objects in runtime based in a external configuración. If I change the configutation, in runtime and without redeploying I would like yo create objects of a diferent class than before. For example, a process is creating objects of class A, an after changing the configutation without redeploying, the process must create objects of class B

Comment: why not use if else logic or something similar? if not possible, please elaborate your specific need

Comment: Because the instantation must depend of external rules. I need to change the behavior of the app, without compile and deploy again.

Comment: What's your exact problem? You dunno how to detect change in external config? You dunno the proper pattern to let you switch between different family of output (which is Abstract Factory)?

Answer (score 1):

You can use newInstance method.

`Class.forName("<<your class name>>").newInstance()`

But you need to typecast the new instance.